# Draw brush missing in texture paint

Tags: texture-painting, brushes

Have been using the draw tool in texture paint on a model but when I open the file now the tool is completely missing. Is it possible to accidentally delete a brush and if so: How do I get it back?

[image]

Comment: Brushes can be created and deleted. The default brushes have a so-called fake user. That's the "F" letter at the beginning of their names. It ensures, that the brushes are saved and not discarded by the garbage collection when you save the blend file. Maybe you have removed the flag accidentally? I would create & save a new file. Then open this file and use *File > Append... > Brushes* to append the missing brush from the saved default blend file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried it out but after pressing append the brush does not show up in brush select window. I've never tried to append before so I don't know if I'm missing some steps. Using Blender 2.74, by the way.

Comment: Edit: Got it to work! Thank you very much!